# find field values specific to a single value of another field and doesn't exist for any other values of that field

Tags: mongodb

how to find field values specific to a single value of another field and doesn't exist for any other values of that field.

for eg. lets consider

```
field1    field2
1          x
1          y
1          z

2          x
2          y
2          w
```

so when i input "1" the output I want is "z" and when I input "2" i get "w"

also i would like to know if this can be further extended to complex filters such as specific values to the a combination of fields in a query

thanks in advance